# How to fetch specific column data from the different tables in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm creating  a website on teacher and student database in php, i have done almost all things in mysql database but i want to fetch specific data from the table, like i want to choose "prof. vaidya sir" from column "name" and display professor related all data.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php   
include 'dbh.php';
$name = "Prof. Vaidya Sir";
$class ="BE";
$sqll = "SELECT feedback1.erp,feedback1.class,feedback2.name,feedback2.ability,feedback2.knowledge,feedback2.accessbility,feedback2.attitude FROM feedback1, feedback2 WHERE feedback1.erp=feedback2.erp";
$result = $conn->query($sqll);
?>
<table border="2">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>erp</th><th>class</th><th>name</th><th>ability</th><th>knowledge</th><th>accessbility</th><th>attitude</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
      if($result->num_rows > 0)
         {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

             echo "<tr><td>{$row["erp"]}</td><td>{$row["class"]}</td><td>{$row["name"]}</td><td>{$row["ability"]}</td><td>{$row["knowledge"]}</td><td>{$row["accessbility"]}</td><td>{$row["attitude"]}</td></tr>\n";

        }   
        else{echo "0 results";
        }
?>
 </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is output of above code**

[image: This is output of above code]

Comment: you need to use a specific `WHERE` with an `AND`.

Comment: you asked for help, you've been given it in forms of answers given below. You can accept the one you wish, or post a comment in regards to if it's working for you or not. If you left the question only to return at a future date and not letting them know if it worked or not, is not good policy.

Comment: Thank u for help it shows prof. vaidya sir related two rows but also shows 1 warning-                                                                         Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param() in C:\xampp\htdocs\sitea\feedback_out.php on line 21 object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(7) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(2) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Thank u for ur help, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for mysql joins.

```sql
SELECT table1.name, table2.col2 
FROM table1
JOIN table2 
ON table1.erp = table2.erp
WHERE table1.name = 'Prof. Vaidya Sir';
```

This says to first join the two tables on their common columns, then select the specific columns you are looking for where the name matches.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this
disclaimer: I don't usually use mysqli so I think I have it right

you should use `JOINS` instead of old way it makes the connection clearer and more human readable

```
<?php 
include 'dbh.php';
$name = "Prof. Vaidya Sir";
$class ="BE";
$sqll = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT feedback1.erp,feedback1.class,feedback2.name,feedback2.ability,feedback2.knowledge,feedback2.accessbility,feedback2.attitude 
         FROM feedback1 join feedback2 ON  feedback1.erp=feedback2.erp
         WHERE feedback2.name =?";

$sqll->bind_param('s', $name);
$sqll->execute();

$result = $sqll->get_result();
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Comment: they're using mysqli not pdo; it's pretty obvious. Now they'd have to totally rewrite and refactor.

Comment: I have modified my answer to use `mysqli` (I think)

Comment: well let's see what they have to say. I posted a comment under their question, and they haven't even responded to my first one. So, it's anybody's ballgame really.

Comment: Thank u for help it shows prof. vaidya sir related two rows but also shows 1 warning-                                                                                                          Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param() in C:\xampp\htdocs\sitea\feedback_out.php on line 21
object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(7) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(2) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the parameter type to the bind function, I corrected my answer, please try again.